# Recent suspend problem on Envy x360

Tags: suspend, laptop, hp, 18.10

I'm running 18.10 on an Envy x360 and sometime in the last week or so it's intermittently failing to sleep/suspend after I close the lid. It works sometimes but it's either usage or just time that causes it to stop. Like if I reboot and suspend in the first few minutes it works. But after using it to surf the web for an hour or so, it doesn't suspend when I close the lid. I can't lift the lid and start working again either.. I have to hard shut down by holding the power button.

Does anybody know what logs I could check to start trouble shooting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else stumbles on this, the logs are in /var/log/syslog. In my case, the GS Connect gnome extension was the cause of the problem. After disabling it, my laptop now suspends and resumes consistently.